# POSTGRESQL : How do I select values A that have multiple pairing values for B?

Tags: sql, postgresql

*Background*

I have a table which is used to track changes in users' accounts.
Column **a** is the primary key for this accounthistory-table, column **b** is a foreign key which contains the primary key for an account from account-table,  column **c** contains the username at the time of change, column **d** has timestamp from the time of the change and column **e** describes what the performed action was, from options INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE.

At a given time there can be only one account **b** with username **c** but across time multiple accounts **b** can have identical username values **c** (see example b=20 and b=07 from table). As there are other columns as well there can be multiple UPDATEs or INSERT + UPDATE for all accounts so each **c** value should have atleast 2 rows after some time has passed from the insert.

*Question:*

Below is an example of the data. **What I need to figure out is "accounts that have had their username change atleast once"** so values of **b** that have multiple rows with differing values for **c**. I'm only interested in the value of column **b** as I need to use the result in further selection queries.

Table accounthistory:

| a | b | c | d | e |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 15 | toma | 2021-11-15 16:22:40.747766 | UPDATE |
| 99 | 20 | valt | 2021-11-13 08:22:40.747766 | UPDATE |
| 98 | 17 | mitk | 2021-11-12 15:22:40.747766 | INSERT |
| 97 | 15 | tomia | 2021-11-10 08:22:40.747766 | UPDATE |
| 96 | 20 | valt | 2021-11-09 07:22:40.747766 | INSERT |
| 95 | 15 | tomia | 2021-10-21 20:22:40.747766 | INSERT |
| 94 | 12 | alek | 2021-10-18 18:22:40.747766 | INSERT |
| 93 | 07 | valt | 2021-10-15 10:22:40.747766 | DELETE |
| 92 | 04 | juur | 2021-10-12 10:22:40.747766 | DELETE |
| 91 | 07 | valt | 2021-10-05 10:22:40.747766 | INSERT |

The expected result would be 15 as it has had both usernames 'tomia' and 'toma', other **b**'s have only matching values for **c** and it doesn't matter that both 07 and 20 have had username 'valt' since 07 was deleted before 20 was added.

So is there a way to select these values for **b**, I tried forming different group by's and other messy queries but as I'm quite novice in the use of postgresql and sql in general I haven't been able to get this to work.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` to determine which column `b` has a least 1 column `c` that does not have the same column `c`. Then employ `distinct on` to eliminate the duplicates.  [Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f2bab8ee22fe8e9cde12f89f1281ec38).

```
select distinct on (b) b 
  from accounthistory ah1
 where exists ( 
                select null 
                  from accounthistory ah2
                 where ah2.b = ah1.b
                   and ah2.c <> ah1.c
              ) 
 order by b;
```